# How to programmatically create a product review for Administrator?

Tags: magento-1.7, php, review

I'm trying to create product review programmatically, using the below code

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1); //desired store id
$review = Mage::getModel('review/review');
$review->setEntityPkValue(1);//product id
$review->setStatusId(1);
$review->setTitle("mytitle");
$review->setDetail("mydetail");
$review->setEntityId(1);                                      
$review->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());      //storeview              
$review->setStatusId(1); //approved
$review->setCustomerId(1);
$review->setNickname("Menickname");
$review->setReviewId($review->getId());
$review->setStores(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
$review->save();
$review->aggregate();
?>
```

When I set customer Id `$review->setCustomerId(1)` like this, it creates review for the product by customer with id=1 and when I use this `$review->setCustomerId()`, it creates review for the product by Guest. But I could not make review by **administrator**, I tried the below

```
$review->setCustomerId(null)
```

This also set review by Guest. How to create review for product by administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SIBHI S, I founded of your issue. Replace the following code as

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1); //desired store id
$review = Mage::getModel('review/review');
$review->setEntityPkValue(1);//product id
$review->setStatusId(1);
$review->setTitle("mytitle");
$review->setDetail("mydetail");
$review->setEntityId(1);                                      
$review->setStoreId(0);      //storeview              
$review->setStatusId(1); //approved
$review->setCustomerId(null);
$review->setNickname("Menickname");
$review->setReviewId($review->getId());
$review->setStores(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
$review->save();
$review->aggregate();
```

I hope this is resolved your issue.

Comment: Is it means,For administrator store should be 0?

Comment: yes. when administrator create a review, its store id store as 0.